# Vb.Net MySQL on Linux with Mono Error

Tags: mysql, .net, linux, vb.net, mono

I have mono-runtime and mono-basic installed on my machine. I've been able to run other vb.net applications on it. However, I'm trying to run a application I made which references to the [latest .Net & Mono MySQL Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/). It works fine when I run it on widows, but when I try to run it on Linux I get:

```
    Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'
  at ASGI.Module1.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'
  at ASGI.Module1.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: Did You copy *.dll of MySQL connector? Exception says that You references dependencies are missing.

Comment: Yes I did, all 4 .dll's are in the same directory as the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to install the .dll to the mono GAC as stated [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Assemblies_and_the_GAC).